# Learning Java 5 Vs Java 7?

Tags: java, java-7, java-5

I'm planning on learning Java, I have experience programming in other Object Oriented languages, so I'm familiar with OOP concepts. At the moment I'm considering two books to help me get a jump start in Java development. "Head first into Java 2nd edition" or "Java All-in-One For Dummies 3rd edition".

Now many people have recommended Head first into Java as the better of the two books for me. However Head first into Java was published in 2005 (unless theirs a more recent edition I'm not aware of) and teaches in Java 5. Java All-in-One was released last August and is updated for Java 7.

Now my question is I'm leaning towards Head first into Java (uses Java5), would I be missing out on important aspects of Java 6 and 7? Would it make a big difference in my ability to become proficient at Java developer?

Comment: You won't be missing much if you start with Java 5. There are a few new APIs and one new language construct. You'll be able to easily catch up with those.

Comment: If by java7 you mean erlang, yes go for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one word: no.

If you want to learn the basic concepts, Java 5 is just as good as Java 7.

The big change was between 4 (the 1.4 series to be more precise) and 5, with the introduction of generics.

Answer (score 3):

Just get started learning Java. When you are more or less proficient you can check whats new.

Depending on where you develop your software you are locked to an older version anyways.